# Prover9 generating wrong proof

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying to find a solution of a first-order logic problem using prover9, the question is:

1. Someone who lives in Maniac Mansion killed Aunt Agatha.
2. Agatha, the butler, and Charles live in Maniac Mansion, and are the only people who live there.
3. A killer always hates their victim, and is never richer than their victim.
4. Charles hates no one that Aunt Agatha hates.
5. Agatha hates everyone except the butler.
6. The butler hates everyone not richer than Aunt Agatha.
7. The butler hates everyone that Aunt Agatha hates.
8. No one hates everyone.
9. Agatha is not the butler.

I need to generate a proof that solves the mystery of who killed Agatha
by entering an appropriate formula into the goal box of the Prover9 software.

I have translated these statements into first-order logic statements in the prover9 form and set the goal to find the killer. And when running it says the butler is the killer of Agatha, but in the next question is explaining who the butler cannot be the killer of Agatha based on the facts provided.

```
%% 1. Someone who lives in Maniac Mansion killed Aunt Agatha.
exists x (LivesMM(x) & Killed(x,agatha)).

%% 2. Agatha, the butler, and Charles live in Maniac Mansion, and are the only people who live there.
LivesMM(agatha) & LivesMM(charles) & LivesMM(butler) & (all x (LivesMM(x) -> ((x=agatha) | (x=charles) | (x=butler)))).

%% 3. A killer always hates his victim, and is never richer than his victim.
all x all y (Killed(x,y) -> (Hates(x,y) & -(Richer(x,y)))).

%% 4. Charles hates no one that Aunt Agatha hates.
all x (Hates(agatha,x) -> -Hates(charles,x)).

%% 5. Agatha hates everyone except the butler.
all x (-(x=butler) -> Hates(agatha,x)).

%% 6. The butler hates everyone not richer than Aunt Agatha.
all x (-Richer(x,agatha) -> Hates(butler,x)).

%% 7. The butler hates everyone Aunt Agatha hates.
all x (Hates(agatha,x) -> Hates(butler,x)).

%% 8. No one hates everyone.
(all x exists y (-Hates(x,y))).

%% 9. Agatha is not the butler.
-(agatha=butler).

end_of_list.

formulas(goals).

%% Who killed Aunt Agatha?

exists x((x=agatha | x=charles | x=butler) & Killed(x,agatha)).

end_of_list.
```

***Problem:***

I expected for the program to prove that the killer was either Agatha or Charles, but not the butler since the next question is explaining why the butler cannot be the killer based on the provided facts above. I don't know what is missing or if I wrongly converted the statements into first-order logic.

Comment: What did the program prove, and how did that differ from your expectation?